# This is the first time I have been driving why is it not idiomatic?

Tags: tense

Why can't I say  **This the first time I have been driving this car** , if I am still driving it and if I have been driving for half an hour .

This could be possible why with this is the first time present perfect continuous does not seem to be idiomatic

Is it because we consider the event in its entirety the emphasis is on the event not on its duration.

Comment: The question is a reasonable one. For instance, it would be idiomatic to say, “This is my first time **driving** this car.” Or, “This is the first time I’ve **gone** driving **in** this car.” But as for the construction you ask about, English simply doesn’t allow it; as you likely know, the idiomatic way to express that thought is *This is the first time I have **driven** this car*. Consider the song title, *The Last Time I Saw Paris*: it would not work as \**The Last Time I **Was Seeing** Paris*.

Answer (score 1):

Consider:

> I have been taking this route to the airport since roadwork began three weeks ago.
>
> I have been taking this route to the airport for many years.

Whether it is a recently adopted practice or a long-term practice, the present perfect continuous has at is core the notion of *habit* or *regular practice* (or similar notions if the thing has no volition, e.g. *the faucet has been dripping*), and thus there is a semantic clash with *the first time*:

> *This is the first time I have been taking this route to the airport.

Comment: Agreed. You could stretch for a singular context where the original sentence works, but not commonly.

Comment: So the last sentence you wrote is wrong the one with a little star

Comment: Yes, the preceding star is just a convention to indicate that what follows is ungrammatical.

Comment: if I change first time by third time does it work with present perfect continuous

Comment: in which context my original sentence could work

Comment: Yes, 'the third time' could work. But it's still a tad shaky ... as if there's more to come.  '.... when the headlights have stopped working', for example.  A reference to a specific number of times is only marginally better than a reference to the first time.

Comment: A reference to a specific number of times is only a tad better than a reference to the first time because it indicates certain thresholds have been crossed more than it indicates habitual behavior.  A specific number of times wants the plain present perfect, **have driven**, not the continuous.  *This is the third time I've driven the car.*

Comment: Even a reference to multiple times doesn't get you out of that situation:  *I have been driving this car many times.  (not idiomatic) .  It isn't the sheer number of times that casts something as habitual, regular, or persistent. An adjunct with a temporal element is needed.

Comment: ... as if there's more to come. '.... when the headlights have stopped working', You mean this is the third time I have been taking this road   when  the headlights have stopped working. This could work . Why?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150605/discussion-between-yves-lefol-and-timr).

Comment: It is the third time that the *ongoing activity of driving the car* has been *punctuated* by an incident with the headlights.  The temporal clause *when the headlights have stopped working* provides an anchor for "have been driving" and the skeletal semantic context is **interruption**.

Comment: so why is it possible if there is more to come you mean what is important in your example is the interruption not the number of times ? right